# Get texts of multiple elements as array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a bunch of `<a href="..." class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want</a>` elements and i want to get all their .text() stuff as array so i can process it further.

Stuff i already tried based on other stackoverflow questions:

```
classes = document.getElementsByClassName("summary-sig-name");
values = [];

for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    values.push(classes[i].value);
}
```

which results in
[image]

```
var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("summary-sig-name"); // Do not use a period here!
var values = Array.prototype.map.call(classes, function(el) {
    return el.innerText;
});
```

which results in
[image]

```
jQuery(".summary-sig-name").text()
```

which results in
[image]
which i very close to what i want but i can't guess where one ends and the next one starts

In case you want to know which page i wan't to "process": https://pytson.4qt.de/ts3plugin.ts3plugin-class.html

Comment: Explain what is the problem?

Comment: And is there a problem with any of those methods?

Comment: @Pedram I did in the first sentence

Comment: @Rory McCrossan i added some results to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget those methods, you just need use `each` loop to get elements `text` and push them into an array like this:

```js
textArray = [];

$('.summary-sig-name').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  textArray.push(text);
});

console.log(textArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 1</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 2</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 3</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 4</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 5</a>
```

But if you want to know why those not working, You should get `innerText` not `value`.

```js
classes = document.getElementsByClassName("summary-sig-name");
textArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
  textArray.push(classes[i].innerText);
}

console.log(textArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 1</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 2</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 3</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 4</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 5</a>
```

And for second one, it works fine:

```js
var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("summary-sig-name");
var textArray = Array.prototype.map.call(classes, function(el) {
  return el.innerText;
});

console.log(textArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 1</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 2</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 3</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 4</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Some Text I Want 5</a>
```

Comment: one thing you should probably replace `values` with `myArray` or something. `values()` seems to be a built in function in atleast FF 47+

Comment: @Bluscream [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands) is a helper command in the Firefox console. Asking about _why `values` doesn’t work_ would make an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this in jQuery then `map()` is by far the simplest way:

```js
let textArray = $('.summary-sig-name').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(textArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Foo</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Bar</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Fizz</a>
<a href="#" class="summary-sig-name">Buzz</a>
```

Also note that your first example doesn't work as you need to use the `innerText` property, not `value`. The second one works fine.